# Calculate polyhedra vertices based on faces

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I have some origami polyhedra which I know the type of faces it has and how they are connected (such as this [torus](http://ditelo.fbk.eu/people/gretter/img/ori/toro_schema.gif)) and I want to calculate the co-ordinates of the vertices to use as an input to [script](https://code.google.com/p/rainbow-phizz-origami-buckyball/downloads/list).

My question is how should I go about translating knowledge of the faces into the locations of the vertices? Are there geometric tricks I can apply? or are there any software libraries/tools I could use to help out here? To make thinks a bit more complicated I don't think all the faces are regular polygons, all the edges should be the same length and all the angles should be the same but being made of paper there is a little wiggle room.

Comment: CGAL is great among all computational geometry libs, but it still can't do what you described: given a 2D collection of faces, wrapping them to a 3d polyhderon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard tool to do this sort of thing is the `polymake` program, which google will find in seconds.

But from the description in your question (which is not very explicit) it seems that `polymake` would not work for you. For example, tori are not convex, and most things work on covex solds, and so on.

Comment: I don't think polymake could wrap a 2d skeleton into a polyhedron...

Comment: Well, one of its make abilities is to compute vertices of polyhedra given by faces, when these are given by equations. I doubt *anything* can compute vertices from a combinatorial description of the 2-skeleton.

Comment: Yeah, it is an NP-hard problem, well.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: A graph's adjacency matrix provides vertices of "harmonious" (automorphisms = isometries) geometric realizations, one for each eigenvalue. (See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/309001/409).) These eigen-realizations may or may not correspond to convex polyhedra (as points, edges, faces may coincide, intersect, or span egregiously-high dimensions), but they give rise to all possible realizations under a proper notion of figural addition (the one corresponding to simple matrix addition). I don't (yet) know a strategy to ensure a convex polyhedral combination.