# Where can I find a good drawing software?

Tags: geometry, math-software

Maybe this is a little off-topic but often, when writing articles, I find myself in need of a good drawing software (for MAC or Windows) that would allow me to draw figures like the one below:

[image: Sphere]

Do you recommend any specific software? I need to draw mathematical figures such as spheres, cylinders, planes and also intersect these objects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TeX and [Tikz/pgf](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/).

Comment: Possibly [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/download)

Comment: Might as well throw a couple more out: Asymptote, Graphmatica, MetaPost, gunplot.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks for posting that link, I didn't know that page before, that'll be very useful.  Man we used to work hard in the old days.

Comment: [Satimage](http://satimage.fr)'s ["Smile"](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/index.html) leverages the Mac's AppleScript language to draw images programmatically. The interface is poor, and the documentation difficult to navigate, but Smile has some built-in geometric primitives and labeling options (including TeX support) that could be helpful. I've used it to create diagrams such as those shown in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/490370/409). See also some of Satimage's [sample images](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/graphics/graphics_samples.html).

Comment: See also: [Software for drawing geometry diagrams](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/). It comes with most TeX installations, and it has native support for 3D objects. It can even embed them into the resulting PDF file in such a way that the users can rotate them, if their PDF viewer supports this.

I know many people prefer [TikZ](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/) over Asymptote. To my knowledge, both tools are comparable in their expressive power, but use very different syntax. Asymptote is more like C, TikZ more like TeX. I don't know about the extent of native 3D support in TikZ.

The benefits of both these tools are that you can easily embed the resulting graphics into a TeX document, and have the fonts and everything matched between text and graphics. If that is not an objective, you can try other tools as well, ranging from general-purpose vector graphics editors like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) through function plotting tools like [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) or dynamic geometry software like [Cinderella](http://cinderella.de/) or [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) to the graphics output facilities of computer algebra systems like [Sage](http://sagemath.org/) or [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). It depends on how you want to specify the object, how interactive you want the creation process to be, and how much post-processing you are willing to perform on the generated image.