# How can one actually use Adjacency Matrix for understanding a graph?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I don't see any real reason why we would use an AM to represent a graph, beside visual appeal and ease. Generally, we would perform matrix operations on Matrices like |A|, Transpose and loads of other things but that magic doesn't seem to add up to what I am looking at, AM. Anyone care to explain or give me some intuition so I may respect AM a bit more and use it to study the graph at hand purely by playing around with the numbers. Obviously, you get the point.

Comment: See e.g. [matrix tree theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_theorem)

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting.

Comment: There's an [entire branch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_graph_theory) of mathematics devoted to the study of matrix representations of graphs. Applications are abound. A rather stunning application of adjacency matrices occur in understanding which parts of a network are the most [central](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvector_centrality#Eigenvector_centrality). This links directly to things like Google's PageRank algorithm for example. This [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308952/motivation-for-spectral-graph-theory) also seems to be related.

Comment: Thanks for your answer EuYu. I read somewhere you could find some interesting things by doing A transpose, not sure though.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308952/motivation-for-spectral-graph-theory/312555#312555 for relevant discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one use of adjacency matrices. Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and let $A(G)=\{a_{ij}\}$ be its adjacency matrix. Then the $ij$-th entry of $A(G)^n$ is the number of walks of length $n$ starting at the $i$-th vertex that end at the $j$-th vertex.

For large $n$, it's inefficient to calculate the $n$-th power of $A(G)$, so we find its eigenvalues to diagonalize $A(G)$: $$A(G)=P^TDP$$
so that $A(G)^n=P^TD^n P$ can be easily calculated.

Comment: An example would be nice.