# Is there a way to visualize a group?

Tags: group-theory, intuition, visualization

Is there a way to picture a group in ones head?

I want to "see" the difference between abelian and non-abelian group.

And if $f$ is a group homomorphism, is there a way to see that $\ker(f)=1\Leftrightarrow f$ is injective?

What about topological groups? All I see is a map between two spaces.

Are there any easy to visualize examples to have in mind?

Comment: perhaps you should read about cayley graphs

Comment: Good question on the first one, but the question of how to visualize a group seems to be totally separate from the question of why we can characterize injective group homomorphisms as those with trivial kernel. Maybe you want to separate that out as a second question.

Comment: For the first question, consider groups of symmetries : The symmetries of a triangle, for instance, forms the non-abelian group $S_3$, while that of the square is $D_4$.

Comment: Consider [this tiling](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Tile_3636.svg). It has many symmetries: six-fold rotation centered at the hexagons, three-fold rotation at the triangles, two-fold rotation at the vertices, horizontal reflection, vertical reflection, glide reflection along the drawn lines, glide reflection along the shorter diagonals of the hexagons, and translational symmetry. These symmetries form a group.

Comment: I don't know if that's the _best_ way to visualize a group — especially since it's kind of hard to add two symmetries in my head — but it's certainly visual.

Comment: Finite groups are sometimes expressed by their multiplication tables.  This does not make it obvious that the associative property holds, but the existence of an identity element and of inverses may be visually checked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I represent groups geometrically?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252746/can-i-represent-groups-geometrically)

Comment: You may be interested in [Group Explorer](http://groupexplorer.sourceforge.net/) and an associated book. Also, this question is a collection of many questions each of which may be answered separately in more than one way. Hence the downvotes, I guess.

Comment: For the abelian/non-abelian question, think of the Cayley table of the (finite) group. It will be symmetric (with respect to the main diagonal) if and only if the group is abelian. Easy to generalise this on the infinite case.