# ELI5: What is spectral graph theory?

Tags: spectral-graph-theory

I am aware that there is already a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308952/motivation-for-spectral-graph-theory), but unfortunately I find the discussion there to be beyond my grasp.

I am looking for an intuitive explanation of spectral graph theory, as well as some examples of its applications in practice. Specifically, I want to know how it might or might not be relevant to image processing and machine learning.

I am comfortable with freshman-level mathematics (such as linear algebra and partial differential equations), but I will be lost if you invoke more advanced concepts in your answer.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Lecture notes (introduction) from a big name in the area ([Dan Spielman](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/eigs/)): http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/eigs/lect1.pdf

Comment: @ClementC. I tried reading the document you linked to, but unfortunately I think it went over my head :-(

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XJes6XFjxM This video is a great introduction and really shows how amazing this area of mathematics is!