# What do the eigenvalues of a graph tell you about the graph?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

I have looked everywhere for a straightforward answer, but there seems to be no explanation for what you can do with the eigenvalues of a graph.

What properties about the graph like connectivity, modeling it as a network, etc. can you tell from the eigenvalues?

Comment: Some answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308952/motivation-for-spectral-graph-theory/312555#312555