# Symmetric matrices with "interesting" spectra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I am looking for symmetric matrices $A \in \{-1,0,1\}^{n \times n}$ that have an "interesting" spectrum.

What do I mean by that?

Suppose we have the following matrix:

$$A_1 := \left( \begin{array}{rr}0 & 1 \\1 & 0 \\\end{array}\right), \qquad A_n :=  \left( \begin{array}{rr} A_{n-1} & I_{n-1} \\I_{n-1} & - A_{n-1} \\\end{array}\right)$$

$A_n $ has spectrum $ \{\sqrt{n}, -\sqrt{n}\}$ each with multiplicity $2^{n-1}$.

(Because $A_n^2 = n \cdot I_n$ and $\mbox{tr} (A_n) = 0$, and since $A_n$ is symmetric its trace is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues each with its corresponding multiplicity).

I am looking for matrices, that have "comparably" interesting spectra, thanks in advance for any creative propositions!

EDIT: for clarifying purposes - any spectrum not solely consisting of $\{-1,1\}$ I'd consider interesting.

Comment: Isn't interesting in the eye of beholder? I cannot really see this as an answerable question.

Comment: thanks @Rahul but Hilbert matrices do not comply to my requirements stated.

Comment: @WillieWong hence the example and "comparably" with quotation marks - I think(hope) it is "answerable".

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309001/409), I briefly discuss my interest in the spectra of adjacency matrices of graphs.

Answer (score 2):

A canonical example for this is 
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0&\cdots&0  \\
1&0&1&0 &\cdots&\vdots\\
0&1&0&1&0 &\vdots\\
\vdots&0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots &\vdots\\
0&\vdots&0&1&0&1 \\
0&\cdots&\cdots&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix} .
$$
It is well-known (since Lagrange, I understand) that the eigenvalues of $S$ are 
$$
2\cos\frac{k\pi}{n+1},\ \ \ \ k=1,\ldots,n.
$$
It is actually easy to check, if you are told to use the eigenvectors 
$$
x_k=\left(\sin\frac{kj\pi}{n+1}\right)_j.
$$